# How to add new custom fields in existing GraphQL API (Query and Mutuation)?

Tags: api, magento2.3.3, custom-field, extend, graphql

I have basic knowledge about GraphQL. Now, I would like to convert my knowledge into action. For that, I want to know about few things like how can I add my custom field to any GraphQL Query and mutations. I have also read some blog posts for this but they don't have proper guidance which I am looking for.

Can someone please explain with example of extending an existing GraphQL API for both Query and Mutations? That would be really handy.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you expecting existing queries & mutation extend or creating custom queries and Mutation?

Comment: @Mujahidh, I am expecting to extend/override existing (default magento) queries and mutations.

Comment: Did you check my answer for your question?

Comment: @Mujahidh, Sorry for late response. I was busy with other stuff. I checked your detailed response. It looks fine and I think it will help me as well. I upvoted your reply. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

We can do our custom endpoints too. I have extend some existing default graphql queries.

1 . Query **storeConfig** -( module-store-graph-ql )

2 . Query **products**'s ProductFilterInput - ( module-catalog-graph-ql )

1 . *Query **storeConfig** -( module-store-graph-ql )*

I extended **storeConfig** using following steps.
create a di.xml file under module's etc/graphql directory and define the new items like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\StoreGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Store\StoreConfigDataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="extendedConfigData">
<!-- Default store config sets-->
    <item name="general_store_information_name" xsi:type="string">general/store_information/name</item>
    <item name="general_store_information_additional_phone" xsi:type="string">general/store_information/additional_phone</item>
    <!-- Custom store config sets-->
    <item name="contact_us_forms_title" xsi:type="string">contact_us/forms/title</item>
    <item name="contact_us_forms_info_title" xsi:type="string">contact_us/forms/info_title</item>
    </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

and write the schema.graphqls file

```
type StoreConfig {
general_store_information_name : String  @doc(description: "Store Name"),
general_store_information_phone : String  @doc(description: "Store Phone Number "),
contact_us_forms_title : String  @doc(description: "contact Us form title text"),
contact_us_forms_info_title : String  @doc(description: "contact Us information section title text")
}
```

After setup:upgrade and chache:clean you can run the graphql query like below to get the result.

```
query{
storeConfig {
    copyright
    general_store_information_name
    trans_email_ident_general_email
    contact_us_forms_title
    contact_us_forms_info_title
}
}
```

For better understanding read [How to get the store configuration values using GraphQl in magento 2?](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-get-the-store-configuration-values-using-graphql-in-magento-2/)

2 . *Query **products**'s ProductFilterInput - ( module-catalog-graph-ql )*
for this section please read [magento 2 graphql product query](https://www.mujahidh.com/how-to-filter-product-collection-with-default-graphql-products-query/)

All these customization i did based on my requirements with personally modification. It's worked out for me. Hope this will help you and some one who read this.

Answer (score 1):

One of the possible ways of extending existing GraphQl is using the GraphQl interface. As for example, you have a new product attribute `barcode` now you want it in GraphQl response. In that case in your custom module's `etc > schema.graphqls` file add as following

```
interface ProductInterface {
  barcode: String @resolver (class: "Vendor\\Module\\Model\\Resolver\\ProductCustomAttribute")
}
```

After implementation flush the cache. You will be get your desire result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It is useful for interface. What about query and mutations? How can I add new fields in those type of api calls?

Answer (score 1):

**Magento 2.4**

> **I will show you how to add custom attributes into product and customer query and mutation**

***1) Add custom attribute into customer query and mutation***

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
type Customer {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Show")
    @resolver(
      class: "\\VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\GetCustomerCustomAttr"
    )
}

input CustomerInput {
  sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Customer Custom Attribute Val")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver**

**GetCustomerCustomAttr.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare (strict_types = 1);

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\Customer\Api\Data\CustomerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;

/**
 * Customer custom attribute field resolver
 */
class GetCustomerCustomAttr implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $customerRepositoryInterface;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepositoryInterface
    ) {
        $this->customerRepositoryInterface = $customerRepositoryInterface;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        if (!isset($value['model'])) {
            throw new LocalizedException(__('"model" value should be specified'));
        }
        /** @var CustomerInterface $customer */
        $customer = $value['model'];
        $customerId = (int) $customer->getId();
        $customerData = $this->customerRepositoryInterface->getById($customerId);

        /* Get customer custom attribute value */
        if ($customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')) {
            $customerAttributeVal = $customer->getCustomAttribute('sample_attributess')->getValue();
        } else {
            $customerAttributeVal = null;
        }

        return $customerAttributeVal;
    }
}
```

> **Run Magento Commands:**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento in:rein
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

> **Get customer custom attribute value**

```
{
  customer {
    email
    sample_attribute
  }
}
```

> **Update customer custom attribute value**

```
mutation {
  updateCustomer(
    input: {
      firstname: "Rob",
      sample_attribute: "Text"
    }
  ) {
    customer {
      firstname
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

**2)Filter, sort, and get product custom attribute in product query**

> Create Custom Attribute with below options values.

[image]

[image]

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

**schema.graphqls**

```
interface ProductInterface {
    sample_attribute: String @doc(description: "Product Custom Attribute Show")
      @resolver(
        class: "VendoreName\\ModuleName\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\AddCustomAttribute"
      )
}

input ProductAttributeFilterInput {
  sample_attribute: FilterEqualTypeInput @doc(description: "Product Data filter with Custom Attribute Value")
}

input ProductAttributeSortInput {
  sample_attribute: SortEnum @doc(description: "Sort by the Product Custom Attribute.")
}
```

**app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Resolver/Product**

**AddCustomAttribute.php**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Resolver\Product;

use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;

/**
 * Product custom attribute field resolver
 */
class AddCustomAttribute implements ResolverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    /**
     * @param Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field $field,
        $context,
        \Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $product = $value['model'];
        $_product = $this->productFactory->create()->load($product->getId());
        return $_product->getData('sample_attribute');
    }
}
```

> **Run Magento Commands:**

```
php bin/magento s:up
php bin/magento in:rein
php bin/magento s:s:d -f
php bin/magento c:c
```

> **For show product custom attribute value**

```
{
  products(filter: { sku: { eq: "24-MB01" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

> **For filter product data using custom attribute**

```
{
  products(filter: { sample_attribute: { eq: "test" } }) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

> **For sort product data using custom attribute**

```
{
  products(search: "bag", sort: {sample_attribute: DESC}) {
    items {
      name
      sku
      sample_attribute
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any way to respond like
storeConfig{
params{
contact_us_forms_title
contact_us_forms_info_title
}
}

Answer (score 0):

I have created extention with graphql API for feedback form with custom table with fields Name, Phone, Email, Feedback and Discliamer. This extention also sent email on data insert though API

```
mutation {
  createQueryFeedbacks(
    input: {
      name: "Rohit kaushik"
      mobile: "9876543210"
      email: "example@gmail.com"
      feedback: "This is my feedback or query to admin"
      disclaimer: "Yes"
    }
  )
  {
    feedback_submit {
      entity_id
      name
      mobile
      email
      feedback
      disclaimer
    }
  }
}
```

or full extenstion code you can check here
https://github.com/kaushikrohit54/feedback