# How to override default products search

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch, elasticsearch, elastic

I need to override default graphq products search to allow typos, so that queries like that:

```
{
    products(
        search: "test"
    ) {
        items {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

```
{
    products(
        search: "tets"
    ) {
        items {
            name
        }
    }
}
```

return same results, I also need them to work with `synonyms` as well

I'm getting the idea I could replace the elastic query with something like that:

```
{
    "query": {
        "fuzzy": {
            "name": "tets"
        }
    }
}
```

1. What classes should I override to accomplish that?
2. How to make it work with synonyms too

Comment: do you want to override graphql? endpoint

Answer (score 0):

**Magento 2.4.x**

You can check in magento default vendor. Please check this **schema.graphqls** file at *magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/etc/schema.graphqls*. In this file there are many query and mutation are define which is by default magento provides. In this file we see below code:

```
products (
        search: String @doc(description: "Performs a full-text search using the specified key words."),
        filter: ProductAttributeFilterInput @doc(description: "Identifies which product attributes to search for and return."),
        pageSize: Int = 20 @doc(description: "Specifies the maximum number of results to return at once. This attribute is optional."),
        currentPage: Int = 1 @doc(description: "Specifies which page of results to return. The default value is 1."),
        sort: ProductAttributeSortInput @doc(description: "Specifies which attributes to sort on, and whether to return the results in ascending or descending order.")
    ): Products
    @resolver(class: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Products") @doc(description: "The products query searches for products that match the criteria specified in the search and filter attributes.") @cache(cacheIdentity: "Magento\\CatalogGraphQl\\Model\\Resolver\\Product\\Identity")
```

For synonyms, you can modify this query as per your requirement. You can also add one more parameter for adding *synonyms* or you can modify the resolver file.

Resolver File Path: **magentoRoot/vendor/magento/module-catalog-graph-ql/Model/Resolver/Products.php**

> **Example: Overwrite GraphQL Resolver File**

**app/code/VendoreName/GraphQLCustomize/etc/graphql**

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products" type="VendoreName\GraphQLCustomize\Model\Resolver\Products"/>

</config>
```

**app/code/VendoreName/GraphQLCustomize/Model/Resolver**

**Products.php**

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendoreName\GraphQLCustomize\Model\Resolver;

use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\Model\Resolver\Products\Query\ProductQueryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Config\Element\Field;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlAuthorizationException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Exception\GraphQlInputException;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Query\ResolverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\GraphQl\Schema\Type\ResolveInfo;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver;
use Magento\CatalogGraphQl\DataProvider\Product\SearchCriteriaBuilder;

/**
 * Products field resolver, used for GraphQL request processing.
 */
class Products implements ResolverInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ProductQueryInterface
     */
    private $searchQuery;

    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchApiCriteriaBuilder;

    /**
     * @param ProductQueryInterface $searchQuery
     * @param SearchCriteriaBuilder|null $searchApiCriteriaBuilder
     */
    public function __construct(
        ProductQueryInterface $searchQuery,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchApiCriteriaBuilder = null
    ) {
        $this->searchQuery = $searchQuery;
        $this->searchApiCriteriaBuilder = $searchApiCriteriaBuilder ??
            \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get(SearchCriteriaBuilder::class);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function resolve(
        Field $field,
        $context,
        ResolveInfo $info,
        array $value = null,
        array $args = null
    ) {
        $data = [];
        $data[] = "You have been overrited resolver file";
        return $data;
    }
}
```

For more Click Here:

1. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353491/82670
2. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/353494/82670